# Protractor work with all angular versions?

Tags: protractor

I m new to Protractor. Before I start using it I want to know if Protractor works with Angular 6/7.

Does it work with all angular versions?

Answer (score 0):

Protractor supports Angular and AngularJS 1.0.6/1.1.4 and higher

Ref: https://www.protractortest.org/#/faq